# how to make the Jquery datepicker validations to work on for default values

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a requirement to validate a start date and end date as shown below:
the problem is that the start date and end dates are having default date at the html itself as shown below:

```
Start Date: <input type="text" id="startDate" value="2017-03-13"/>
End Date: <input type="text" id="endDate" value="2017-03-13"/>
```

when i add datepicker and some validations for that start date and end date, the validations are not working on the default values that was given in the html code, how can i make start date and end date validations to work for the dates given in the html values also.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#startDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  }).bind("change", function() {
    var minValue = $(this).val();

    minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
    minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate() + 1);
    $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue);

  });

  $("#endDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true

  }).bind("change", function() {

    var maxValue = $(this).val();
    maxValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", maxValue);
    maxValue.setDate(maxValue.getDate() - 1);
    $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxValue);

  });

  $(".ui-datepicker").css({
    "font-size": "12px"
  });

  $("#startDate").keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  function validateQty(event) {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46 ||
      event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) {
      return true;
    } else if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
      return false;
    } else return true;
  };

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


</head>
<body>
Start Date: <input type="text" id="startDate" value="2017-03-13"/>
End Date: <input type="text" id="endDate" value="2017-03-23" onkeypress='return validateQty(event);'/>
<input type="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the jsfiddle code as below:[enter link description here][1]

https://jsfiddle.net/Manishankarg/ncgg8t9x/1/

Comment: Your link brings me to the homepage of `jsfiddle.net` .

Comment: please check now.

Comment: So, I removed a lot of repetitive code and also applied the prevent default to both.  Is that what you wanted?  https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/ncgg8t9x/4/

Comment: Great you reduced my code to half, thanks for this, but my problem is the validations that you have given are not working for the first time ie..,whenever you run the application and if you check the start date, the datepicker should restrict the user not to add more than end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the issue with the code.  You aren't checking when the page first loads.  And I fixed your code for the selection region. So, here's the new version.  I invoked the input event on page load, that way we immediately run our validation script.

https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/ncgg8t9x/6/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#startDate, #endDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  }).bind("change", function() {
    if ($(this).is("#startDate")) {
      var minValue = $(this).val();
      minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
      minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate() + 1);
      $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue);
    } else {
      var maxValue = $(this).val();
      maxValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", maxValue);
      maxValue.setDate(maxValue.getDate() - 1);
      $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxValue);
    }
  });

  $(".ui-datepicker").css({
    "font-size": "12px"
  });

  $("#startDate, #endDate").keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("#startDate, #endDate").trigger("change");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Start Date: <input type="text" id="startDate" value="2017-03-13"/>
End Date: <input type="text" id="endDate" value="2017-03-23" onkeypress='return validateQty(event);'/>
<input type="submit"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the code you send is working really good.